# What are the differences among "go on a trip", "take a trip", & "make a trip"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

[In the dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/trip)

> **go on a trip** (=go somewhere and come back)
>
> I’ve been on a coach trip to France.
>
> **take a trip** (=go somewhere for pleasure)
>
> Take a trip on the Santa Fe railway or cruise on a Mississippi paddle
>   boat.
>
> **make a trip** (=go somewhere, and perhaps come back)
>
> I couldn’t see him making the long trip to Minneapolis alone.

I don't understand what they mean.

Could you explain it more clearly?

Comment: How more clearly can it be explained?

Answer (score 1):

Generally they are interchangeable.

- "**take a trip**" is the most common/casual way of saying it.
- Some in UK like to use "**go on a trip**" which is quite rarely used in US.
- "**make a trip**" is mostly about emphasising the destination and also often used to speak about preparations and planning.

> English, as any other language, has several ways to express thoughts.

P.S. **Between** is preferred when we talk about a relationship of difference, no matter how many people or things are involved. So the correct title for your questions should have better been "**What are the differences between “go on a trip”, “take a trip”, & “make a trip”?**"